# How can I configure Hudson to send an email for EVERY build, not just those that change the project's status?

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration, build-automation, hudson

I've recently migrated my CI server from an old version of CruiseControl to Hudson.  The only feature I miss from CruiseControl is the ability to receive email build notices of EVERY build, not just those that cause the status of the project to change.

I'm ESPECIALLY interested in build notifications for all successful builds.

Anyone out there doing this?  Or is it time for me to learn Hudson plugin development?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You want to install the [Email-ext](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin) plugin.  It will allow you to configure emails notices for each build.

I use it to send emails for successful builds.  You can configure it send the email to the committers, or a fixed list of recipients.

Comment: I have used "Always" trigger in Email-ext plugin but I am getting mails for everything else except successful build.

Answer (score 14):

When configuring your project, under "Editable Email Notification", there is a
button "Advanced...", which, upon clicking, reveals a number of items, including
a dropdown labelled "Add a trigger:". One of the options is "Success".

Comment: But only if you have the Email-ext plugin installed; which is what the accepted answer mentioned some two months back.

Answer (score 0):

You should not see this error message after you click on `Hudson->ManageHudson->configure System`. Then you configure email.